How to convert model.h5 to TensorFlow; tensorflowjs_converter: command not found
I have a model.h5 and I want to use it on my site, so I want to convert it to TensorFlow JS. For this, I need to use the tensorflowjs_converter. I tried installing tensorflowjs with the following command:
sudo pip install tensorflowjs --break-system-packages
But when I try to run the command to convert, this is what I get:
ice@ice-Mint-PC:~$ tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras "/home/ice/Downloads/handwritten (1).h5" \
/home/ice/Desktop
tensorflowjs_converter: command not found
